# Why GET Method data not enter to database in one same page

Tags: get

I want to get id data to enter value to database
First Script, it's work.
But in second script not work.
This is my first script

```
<?php
        include 'connect.php';
        $id_event=$_GET['id_event']; //it's work
        $assign="SELECT * FROM event where id_event='".$id_event."'";
        $show_data=mysql_query($assign);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($show_data))
            {

    ?>
```

This is my second sript

```
    $id_event=$_GET["id_event"];
    $track_id = $_POST["track_id"];


    case "upload":
    $action = "upload";
    $values = "'".$track_id."','".$id_event."'"; //this is the problem
    $field = "track_id,id_event";               //$id_event not enter to  database
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use $_POST['id_event'] instead of $_GET['id_event']

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But, this is diffrent issue.

id_event come from
echo "<a href='search_event.php?id_event=".$row['0']."'>";

so, i want get that id_event from above.